# Put HTML properly in Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, presentation, openxml-powertools

I am using Openxml SDK, c# to generate Presentation and working so far with plain text, what I am trying now is HTML (entered in a text box) into Presentation. I looked through OpenXML PowerTools but it does not contain converting HTML to Presentation ML, only has HTML to Word ML.

Did anyone try to achieve this? Please let me know if there are more questions OR help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to put rendered HTML-file as some text element on PowerPoint slide?

Comment: @Adam Yes, i am getting data from WYSIWYG and need to apply correct run, para properties. The complicated scenarios is nested html elements like <b><i>this test is bold and underlined</b></i>